# Razorpay Webhook signature verification error

Tags: python, flask, razorpay

I am getting `TypeError: encoding without a string argument` when trying to verify webhook request received from Razorpay.

I have written the code in Python3.6 using Flask.

I understand it has something to do with `request.data` I am passing as argument, but not able to solve the issue.

Below is the code for that is executed when the webhook is called:

```
@app.route('/razorpay', methods=['POST'])
def razorpay_webhook():
    webhook_secret: str = MY_WEBHOOK_SECRET
    signature = request.headers['X-Razorpay-Signature']
    client = razorpay.Client(auth=(MY_KEY, MY_SIGNATURE))
    verify = client.utility.verify_webhook_signature(request.data, signature, webhook_secret)
```

The error I am getting is below:

```
2018-12-10T13:32:16.177198+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-12-10 13:32:16,174] ERROR in app: Exception on /razorpay [POST]
2018-12-10T13:32:16.177227+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-12-10T13:32:16.177229+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
2018-12-10T13:32:16.177231+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
2018-12-10T13:32:16.177233+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
2018-12-10T13:32:16.177235+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
2018-12-10T13:32:16.177237+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
2018-12-10T13:32:16.177238+00:00 app[web.1]:     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
2018-12-10T13:32:16.177240+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
2018-12-10T13:32:16.177243+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise value
2018-12-10T13:32:16.177244+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
2018-12-10T13:32:16.177246+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self.dispatch_request()
2018-12-10T13:32:16.177247+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
2018-12-10T13:32:16.177250+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
2018-12-10T13:32:16.177251+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/app.py", line 81, in razorpay_webook
2018-12-10T13:32:16.177253+00:00 app[web.1]:     verify = client.utility.verify_webhook_signature(request.data, signature, webhook_secret)
2018-12-10T13:32:16.177255+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/razorpay/utility/utility.py", line 25, in verify_webhook_signature
2018-12-10T13:32:16.177256+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.verify_signature(body, signature, secret)
2018-12-10T13:32:16.177258+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/razorpay/utility/utility.py", line 30, in verify_signature
2018-12-10T13:32:16.177260+00:00 app[web.1]:     body = bytes(body, 'utf-8')
2018-12-10T13:32:16.177269+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: encoding without a string argument
```

**EDIT**

Changing the line in code with `request.data` to `str(request.data)` solved the above error. But now I am getting new error as below:

```
2018-12-11T04:24:16.973496+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-12-11T04:24:16.973500+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
2018-12-11T04:24:16.973502+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
2018-12-11T04:24:16.973503+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
2018-12-11T04:24:16.973505+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
2018-12-11T04:24:16.973507+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
2018-12-11T04:24:16.973508+00:00 app[web.1]:     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
2018-12-11T04:24:16.973510+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
2018-12-11T04:24:16.973512+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise value
2018-12-11T04:24:16.973514+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
2018-12-11T04:24:16.973515+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self.dispatch_request()
2018-12-11T04:24:16.973517+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
2018-12-11T04:24:16.973519+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
2018-12-11T04:24:16.973520+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/app.py", line 81, in razorpay_webook
2018-12-11T04:24:16.973522+00:00 app[web.1]:     verify = client.utility.verify_webhook_signature(str(request.data), signature, webhook_secret)
2018-12-11T04:24:16.973524+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/razorpay/utility/utility.py", line 25, in verify_webhook_signature
2018-12-11T04:24:16.973526+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.verify_signature(body, signature, secret)
2018-12-11T04:24:16.973527+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/razorpay/utility/utility.py", line 45, in verify_signature
2018-12-11T04:24:16.973529+00:00 app[web.1]:     'Razorpay Signature Verification Failed')
2018-12-11T04:24:16.973536+00:00 app[web.1]: razorpay.errors.SignatureVerificationError: Razorpay Signature Verification Failed
```

I've double checked, all the values I am passing are correct. So what could be the problem?

Comment: Have you solved this problem ?
Have you any solution please share , i am stuck in this problem ??

Comment: Sorry but I was not able to solve this at that time and we later switched from Razorpay to another service so din't look into this after that.

Comment: You can verify user-agent as a step for verification but signature verification is recommended. @RaviBhushan

Comment: i have posted answer that is working, try it

Answer (score 0):

After  stringify json request data, it is working in  django, try this , it will work 100%

```
payload_body = json.dumps(request.data, separators=(',', ':'))
    verify = client.utility.verify_webhook_signature(payload_body, signature, webhook_secret)
```

if get problem in flask, then use

```
payload_body = json.dumps(request.json, separators=(',', ':'))
```

Comment: Did you read after the EDIT: in question ? The 1st error was solved, and was getting a second error

Comment: yes, i was getting same error, this solution has resolved both problem

Comment: Okay, I'll check it out in while. As we have switched the service. I do have the old code somewhere.

Comment: Yeah, will do that

Comment: @RaviBhushan I tried your solution and I get "Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable". Could you clarify?

Comment: where i  get razorpay_signature

Answer (score 0):

Converting the webhook request body into a string and removing all trailing spaces and fixing the indent level helps.

```
import razorpay
client = razorpay.Client(auth=("<YOUR_KEY_ID>", "<YOUR_KEY_SECRET>"))
client.utility.verify_webhook_signature(json.dumps(body, separators=(',', ':')), signature, secret)
```

Comment: I tried this, but I getting Razorpay Signature Verification Failed. I also tried     `verify = client.utility.verify_webhook_signature(request.data.decode('utf-8'), webhook_signature, webhook_secret)` and the output is None.

Answer (score 0):

Razorpay webhook signature validation using Java (posting as it maybe helpful for others struggling on similar integration)

```java
@POST
@Path("/event")
public Response webhookEvent(@Context HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException,RazorpayException {
    String signature = request.getHeader("X-Razorpay-Signature");
    String body = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream())));
    if(!isValidRequest(body, signature, "your secret")) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
    }
    JSONObject event = new JSONObject(body);
    // do stuff with the event
    return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).build();
}

private boolean isValidRequest(String body, String signature, String secret) throws RazorpayException {
    if(!Utils.verifyWebhookSignature(body, signature, secret)) {
        log.error("Invalid signature received in the request {}", signature);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```